# Technical details of method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've found that most texts are rather vague about the finer details of the method of characteristics. Can anyone point me to a more precise treatment (the pedantic kind)? For instance, for the Cauchy problem  problem $a(x,y)u_x + b(x,y)u_y=c(x,y,u)$ with the condition $u(\phi(s),\psi(s))= g(s), \forall s \in J$ with $J$ an open interval and $a,b,c \text{ and } g \in C^1$ and $b(\phi(s),\psi(s))\phi'(s)-a(\phi(s),\psi(s))\psi'(s)\ne 0, \forall s \in J$. The thing that eludes me is how the characteristics are, as it were, glued together in order to make the inverse function argument work. I'm guessing that the answer lies in the theory of systems of ODE's, but I've never found a more or less precise statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probable read Evans' PDEs text. Alternatively, for a decent video see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpHqrlrU5pM).

Comment: Actually, that does not help. Same shit everywhere. In order to apply the inverse function or implicit function theorem, certain conditions have to be met. Understanding why these conditions hold is the only difficult thing about the method of characteristics and it's the one thing nobody talks about.